# Google analytics API showing data of the wrong user

Tags: oauth, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

i have 2 gmail account (A & B) with each has its own seperate google
   analytics account.

I created an web application following
   http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/

- i login in with account A and i get all profiles under account A
  (which is correct)
- i login with account B from another computer and i get account "A"
  accounts !!!!!!!

the code as follows:

```
<?php    
require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start(); 

// ********************************************************  //
// Get these values from https://console.developers.google.com
// Be sure to enable the Analytics API
// ********************************************************    //
$client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("MY_APP_NAME");
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setState(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users.readonly'));
$client->setAccessType('offline');   // Gets us our refreshtoken

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    if ($_GET['logout'] == "1") {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    }
}

// Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

// Step 1:  The user has not authenticated we give them a link to login    
if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}    

// Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    d($_SESSION['token']);
    print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);   
    $google_oauth =new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
    $google_account = $google_oauth->userinfo->get();       
    // request user accounts
    $accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();
    foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $item) {
    echo "<b>Account:</b> ",$item['name'], " : " , $item['id'], "<br /> \n";
    foreach($item->getWebProperties() as $wp) {
        echo '-----<b>WebProperty:</b> ' ,$wp['name'], " : " , $wp['id'], "<br /> \n";    
        $views = $wp->getProfiles();
        if (!is_null($views)) {
            foreach($wp->getProfiles() as $view) {
                echo '----------<b>View:</b> ' ,$view['name'], " : " , $view['id'], "<br /> \n";    
            }
        }
    }
} 
}
function d($o){
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($o); 
    echo("</pre>");
}
?>



The tutorial for this file can be found at <a href='http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/'>Google Oauth php</a><br>
```

what am i doing wrong!

any idea?

Comment: Can you please provide your code and what actions you are taking?

Comment: i edited my question, thank :)

Comment: my guess something with the session.   try session_destroy(); on the logout.   or maybe unset($_SESSION['token']);   That was a quick tutorial I did to show someone a while ago I never got around to really testing it.   Let me know if it works.

Comment: tried all that , still same issue.. as i mentioned, i 'm trying to login with another gmail account from completely another computer on other network.

Comment: In its raw form, the web is stateless -- the server doesn't know one pageview from the next. A 'session' is an abstract thing created by sending a token to the browser on the first pageview, which should be returned on subsequent pageviews. Then the server can 'join' the two views into a common 'session'....[I don't code in PHP, but that's my guess]

Answer (score 0):

Make sense to check again, to which GA accounts has access your "A" google account, and to which GA accounts has access "B" google account.

If you are logged by another browser from another computer under "B" account and seeing GA accounts for "A", then "A" and "B" are related with each other: 
looks script above showing **only** GA accounts, available to the current GA account.

Theoretically, this may happend because one of following:

- "B" has access to the "A" GA accounts;
- May be Google shows all available GA accounts (both for "A" and "B") - not sure on this;
- May be you're thinking, that logged by "B", but you are logged under "A" google account(how to check: output google account email on the page with PHP, if this not done yet).

These are only ideas, hope some of them will help you. Anyway, I think script is correct, and the issue is on the google accounts and GA access.